# Issue Exporting .app Using Processing and Leap Motion SDK

Tags: java, jar, processing, leap-motion

I have been trying to export a standalone application for Mac using the "Export Application" function in Processing. The simple application, which involves updating a float value on the screen that corresponds to the y-axis position of a hand detected by a Leap Motion, works perfectly well within Processing. However, once I export the application and try to run it, the app opens for a brief second and quickly closes. I have exported applications from Processing successfully before, but not one that uses the Leap SDK. I am using the LeapMotion library for Processing to access the Leap SDK: https://github.com/heuermh/leap-motion-processing. Here is my code:

```
import processing.core.*;
import com.leapmotion.leap.processing.*;
import com.leapmotion.leap.Controller;
import com.leapmotion.leap.Listener;

public class Test extends PApplet {

  Controller controller;
  MyListener listener;
  float position = 0.0f;

  class MyListener extends Listener {
    public void onFrame(Controller controller) {
      if (!controller.frame().hands().isEmpty()) {
        position = controller.frame().hands().leftmost().palmPosition().get(1);
      }
    }
  }

  public void setup() {
    size(600,600);
    controller = new Controller();
    listener = new MyListener();
    controller.addListener(listener);
  }

  public void draw() {
    background(0);
    textAlign(CENTER,CENTER);
    textSize(50);
    text(position, 300,300);
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    PApplet.main("Test");
  }
}
```

When I export the application, the contents of the application are as follows:

```
Info.plist
Java
-core.jar
-gluegen-rt-natives-macosx-universal.jar
-gluegen-rt.jar
-jogl-all-natives-macosx-universal.jar
-jogl-all.jar
-LeapJava.jar
-LeapMotion.jar
-libLeap.dylib
-libLeapJava.dylib
-Test.jar
MacOS
-Test
Plugins
-jdk1.7.0_45.jdk
Resources
-en.lproj
-sketch.icns
PkgInfo
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

P.S. I've already tried bundling the program into a runnable JAR file.

Comment: Since you have a runable jar, do you see any exceptions when you invoke `java -jar yourApp.jar` on the command line?

Comment: go to the Terminal, cd (i.e cd /Applications) to your newly created app and open it (i.e open Test.app). You should get some sort of trace of the error... If you don't, try changing the directory inside the Java folder in the app (i.e cd /Applications/Test.app/Java) and do java -jar Test.jar. That at least should throw something in the terminal...

Comment: Is it possible that the Test.jar file is not recognizing the core.jar file in the package?

Comment: UPDATE: I added a Class-Path to the Manifest file of the Test.jar file indicating all the necessary libraries, and running "java -jar Test.jar" worked perfectly. However, when I try to run Test.app, the app still opens and immediately closes.

Comment: try defining the libraries with an absolute path in the Manifest, test the jar again and then the app

Comment: When I add absolute paths to the Manifest, the jar still works with the "java -jar Test.jar" command, but the app still refuses to open.

Comment: When I export from Processing, my Leap Motion App looks a little different than what you show. The differences are that my ``Java`` folder is inside the ``Resources`` folder and the ``MacOS`` folder contains: ``JavaApplicationStub``, ``libLeap.dylib``, and ``libLeapJava.dylib``. These two LM libraries are in both the MacOS and Java folders.

Comment: Interesting. What version of Processing are you using?

Comment: I was using v2.0.3, but I just saw there is now v.2.1. I just tried it and exporting no longer works out-of-the-box. I had to copy libLeap.dylib and libLeapJava.dylib to the MacOS folder (alongside the executable). Otherwise, I get a "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no LeapJava in java.library.path" error. This is a common problem: since it isn't always easy or obvious how to set this path or that you need to, the Java Leap library cannot find the native Leap libraries -- unless you put them in the default location, namely alongside the executable.

Comment: It seems like Processing 2.1 might have moved what the OS considered to be the executable into the MacOSX folder, but it doesn't automatically copy the Leap Motion native libraries there. I went back to v2.0, and noticed that the Leap libraries weren't copied this time. (Perhaps I copied them manually at some point and forgot.) However, my app worked under 2.0.3 without the Leap libraries in MacOSX, just not in v2.1. I suspect that your problem is the same, but possibly masked since you are using a runnable Jar -- try copying the native Leap libraries to the MacOS folder.